# Angular 2 How to store items in memory

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning AngularJS2 and following the My Hero tutorial in their site I'm building an app and I'm trying to understand how to store items in memory.

This is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-warehouse',
  templateUrl: 'templates/warehouse.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['css/warehouse.component.min.css']
})
export class WarehouseComponent {

    ingredients: Ingredient[] = [
        {"id": 100, "name": "Milk", "description": "White and delicious.", "quality": 0, "price": 10, "quantity": 20},
        {"id": 101, "name": "Cocoa", "description": "Ready to be processed into sweet chocolate.", "quality": 0, "price": 20, "quantity": 50},
        {"id": 102, "name": "Sugar", "description": "The magic behind the choco.", "quality": 0, "price": 5, "quantity": 10}
    ];

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _ingredientService: IngredientService){
    }

    addIngredient(){

        var ingr = jQuery.extend({}, this._ingredientService.getIngredient(104));
        ingr.quantity = 15;
        ingr.quality = 0;

        this.ingredients.push(ingr);
    }

}
```

I have an array called `ingredients` with some ingredients already constructed and when i use addIngredient() I get another ingredient from the service and push it to the array.

The issue is that everytime I switch Components and go back to the Warehouse component the ingredient list is reseted, like if the array was never modified even if the ingredient list is outside the constructor.

Am I doing something wrong? The docs are not very clear regarding this and I would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: You could keep the list of ingredients out of the component class, which is recreated everytime you navigate to it, this way you'll be mutating a global array instead of a class property. See for example this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/236GOzUbemgGNwnKO7fD?p=info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

- The solution provided by Eric.
- Use a shared service. Especially if you want to share these data against several component. In this case, the service must be defined when bootstrapping the application and doesn't specify again in the `providers` attribute of components.
- If you component is involved into routing, you can use the `CanReuse` interface to tell Angular2 to reuse the same instance of the component. See this doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html

Comment: Thank you, all the answers are valid but Ill accept yours because you give more alternatives. Including the array in the service worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `ingredients` array inside your `IngredientService` and add the service into the bootstrap method :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ...,
    IngredientService]);
```

`IngredientService` will be a singleton and your ingredients array will not be reseted